# Clickable list item that select a radio

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html... When I click on the li item I would like the radio input to toggle. I know you can  wrap the whole thing in a label but I can not change the HTML (only the JS and CSS).

Any ideas?

```
    <li>
    <input type="radio" name="KETELWIZARD_TYPE_WONING" data-label="Appartement" value="Appartement | Appartement">Appartement                                                                
    <span class="image">
    <img src="https://acceptatie.foursites.nl/feenstra-ketelkiezer/wp-content/uploads/appartement.png" height="24" width="23" alt="">
    </span>    
    </li>
```

Comment: I also don't think it is valid HTML to have a `span` containing an `image` element (only other inline elements).

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution, using jQuery:

```
$('li').click(function() {

    $(this).find(':radio').prop('checked', true);

});
```

I'd make a more specific selector if I were you, because this will apply to all `<li>` elements on the page. So make sure your parent `<ul>` has a specific ID or class. Then change the code to:

```
$('#yourselector li').click(function() {

    $(this).find(':radio').prop('checked', true);

});
```

Comment: This will not work correctly if he adds any other inputs in the future

Comment: As a suggestion consider using `prop` method instead of the `attr`.

Comment: so u down vote mine then change yours to match mine? nice.

Comment: @undefined your are absolutely right, will edit the post

Comment: @Brian I got downvoted to. I didn't downvote you. Mine is on 0, because somebdy also upvoted (I guess @undefined).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want clicking anywhere on the LI to check the radio, then:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zg6uLxg4/1/

```
$("li").click(function () {
    $(this).find(":radio").prop('checked', true);
});
```

if you want it to toggle (I think you probably would):

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zg6uLxg4/2/

```
$("li").click(function () {
    var $radio = $(this).find(":radio")
    $radio.prop('checked', !$radio.prop('checked'));
});
```

Comment: Just to show it works with multiple LIs: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/zg6uLxg4/6/

Answer (score 1):

You can still wrap radio and spans with javascript:

```
$('.list input:radio').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().wrapInner('<label>');
});
```

Note: `.list` is the way to select `ul`, adjust selector to your needs.

```js
$('.list input:radio').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().wrapInner('<label>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="KETELWIZARD_TYPE_WONING" data-label="Appartement" value="Appartement | Appartement"/> Appartement
        <span class="image">
            <img src="https://acceptatie.foursites.nl/feenstra-ketelkiezer/wp-content/uploads/appartement.png" height="24" width="23" alt=""/>
        </span> 
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="KETELWIZARD_TYPE_WONING" data-label="Appartement" value="Appartement | Appartement"/> Appartement
        <span class="image">
            <img src="https://acceptatie.foursites.nl/feenstra-ketelkiezer/wp-content/uploads/appartement.png" height="24" width="23" alt=""/>
        </span> 
    </li>
</ul>
```